# Can you do multiple refunds / rebates to one realex transaction?

Tags: realex-payments-api

I currently have an issue whereby I am processing single purchases that contain multiple items as one transaction in realex. But when I come to refund say 2 of 4 of these items once I have a refunded the first item and I try and refund the second item I get an error from Realex saying that the transaction has already been refunded.

This is a more high level question as to whether or not it is even possible to do multiple refunds to one Realex transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question. It is possible to process multiple refunds (or rebates as we refer to them) against a single transaction. This isn't setup by default on your account, however. You can email your account manager and request that multiple rebates be enabled.

Best,

Seán

**Channel Support**

**Realex Payments**